# How would I hide a Numeric Keyboard when screen is tapped on my app? (Java)

Tags: java, android

I have an EditText input set to Phone as well as my entire layout set to focusable=true

in my Main Activity XML

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relSafePassage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:onClick="hideKeyboard"
        android:focusable="true">

<EditText
                android:id="@+id/phoneNum"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:backgroundTint="#000000"
                android:ems="9"
                android:text=""
                android:hint="@string/numHint"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:numeric="decimal"
                android:maxLength="9"
                android:visibility="visible"

                tools:ignore="Deprecated,TextFields" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

But when I tap my screen it replaces the Numeric keyboard with the Soft Keyboard instead of hiding it.
This is the Java Code I used to try hide to hide the keyboard:

```
public void hideKeyboard(View view) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void hideKeyboard(View view) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Comment: hello, I have tried this but it seems to give me the same problem. could you clarify where I would find the view in the activity, to replace mView with? I'm still fairly new to coding

Comment: I just edited my answer to include the info about the view as well. check it out.

Comment: And when you call the hideKeyboard method, pass your textview as the view parameter.

Comment: thank you, it turns out what I assumed you meant by my view was correct, your answer was correct but the problem was with my XML
I changed:
`android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:focusable="true"`
with:
`android:focusable="false"
        tools:ignore="KeyboardInaccessibleWidget`

Comment: if the answer helped you in any way, an upvote or a correct answer mark would be nice ;)